# Are memory leaks possible with decltype(new any_type())?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, g++

I am checking for any memory leaks possibility with class pointers using `valgrind` and found out that following program has no memory leaks :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class base{};

int main()
{
  unique_ptr<base> b1 = make_unique<base>();
  base *b2 = new base();
  cout << is_same<decltype(new base()), decltype(b1)>::value << endl;
  cout << is_same<decltype(new base()), decltype(b2)>::value << endl;
  delete b2;
  return 0;
}
```

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The operand of `decltype` (and also `sizeof`) is not evaluated, so any side-effects, including memory allocation, won't happen. Only the type is determined, at compile-time.

So the only memory allocations here are in `make_unique` and the first `new base()`. The former is deallocated by the `unique_ptr` destructor, the latter by `delete b2`, leaving no leaks.

Comment: A particularly interesting consequence of this is functions like [std::declval](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) which are specifically for use in these sorts of expressions, e.g. `decltype(std::declval<type_with_unknown_constructor>().method())`, and in fact are not actually defined anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

`decltype` is a keyword used to query the *type* of an expression. It just analyzes the type of the expression; it doesn't actually perform it.

So, not only will this not leak, you can `decltype` the square root of -1 without any error, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Because `decltype` and template handling (like the type-trait classes) is *compile time* only. Nothing actually happens in run-time.